# Add a simple authentication in a React app w/o a real backend

Tags: reactjs, authentication

I'm trying to make sense of [this tutorial.](https://medium.com/better-programming/building-basic-react-authentication-e20a574d5e71)

When it comes to token auth, I'm blocked because I don't have an API. This is the suggested the piece of code of in Login component:

```js
function postLogin() {
    axios.post("https://www.somePlace.com/auth/login", {
      userName,
      password
    }).then(result => {
      if (result.status === 200) {
        setAuthTokens(result.data);
        setLoggedIn(true);
      } else {
        setIsError(true);
      }
    }).catch(e => {
      setIsError(true);
    });
  }
```

My question is: is there a way to have a fake mock backend so that I can point my axios.post call to it? Or any other suggestion you might have that can help move forward.

Comment: what is handling authentication for your app?

Comment: You can try firebase. It provides a backend for you with minimal setup. It also supports authentication. Though you may need to use the sdk for that https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/start

Comment: @Joe: As specified in the article above (see the tutorial link), it is done with Login component that makes a call to an obvious url w/ axios.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to mock out the authentication to try out the UI, you could do e.g.

```
function postLogin() {
    Promise.resolve({status: 200, data: ""}).then(result => {
      if (result.status === 200) {
        setAuthTokens(result.data);
        setLoggedIn(true);
      } else {
        setIsError(true);
      }
    }).catch(e => {
      setIsError(true);
    });
  }
```

In this case, `Promise.resolve(...)` will just return an object with the properties to proceed with your code.

Obviously this is not something you would want to do outside of a toy example.